# What aircraft model is this that crashed?

Tags: aircraft-identification, accidents

Could someone please tell me what aircraft type this is? The crash happened very near to my flight school a few days ago and I want to know if it was one of their fleet that crashed.

[image: Aircraft crash]

Comment: This is why it's generally a bad idea to head for roads during forced landings unless there are no other options, say because of rocky/hilly terrain. And if you do, look for poles/towers, not wires, when trying to make it down.

Comment: This question shows zero research effort. It's not hard to type the clearly visible registration number in any search engine.

Comment: If you want to know if one of your flight school's aircraft crashed, why not ask the flight school?

Comment: @Sean That's rather insensitive. "Hi, I'm just calling to see if one of your students died today..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a [Cirrus SR22T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrus_SR22), registered in Guernsey as 2-RORO.

The registrar published a [statement](https://www.2-reg.com/2-reg-statement-on-the-2-roro-accident/) including the following information:

> The Guernsey Director of Civil Aviation (DCA) and SGI Guernsey Ltd.
>   (2-REG) confirm that an accident involving a Cirrus SR22T aircraft,
>   registration 2-RORO, occurred on May 12, 2019 between Raglan and
>   Abergavenny, Monmouthshire, Wales, United Kingdom. The accident
>   aircraft had been registered in Guernsey since August 1, 2018. The
>   three occupants of the aircraft were reportedly taken to hospital with
>   minor injuries. No further casualties have been reported.

According to the Aviation Safety Network, [2-RORO](https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/225031) was owned by Transport Safety Resolutions Ltd. On May 12th, 2019 it departed from Denham (EGLD) and crashed at the A40 in Monmouthshire, Wales, UK:

> The aircraft hit some overhead trainwiring during a forced landing and
>   impacting a main road between Raglan and Abergavenny, Monmouthshire,
>   Wales. It was consumed by the post-impact fire.

[image]
<sup>Image of better times by Andrew Goldsmith on Flickr, 09-05-2019</sup>

---

There was already an (only seemingly similar) event on the A40 between Raglan and Abergavenny in June 25th, 2016. A Piper PA-28 ([G-SVEA](https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/wiki.php?id=188373)) tried to depart from Abergavenny airfield - a gras strip just next to the A40. It stroke some trees, veered onto the highway and crashed into the central lane separation.

Comment: Maybe it's the broken wing, but the registration could also be 2-RORG. I must admit, my initial instinct was 2-RORO, though.

Comment: Other than paint, I'm not seeing the resemblance. Must have been one heck of a crash.

Comment: Even with the last letter being a little difficult to read, plugging `2-RORG` into a search engine comes back with no useful results for me, while `2-RORO` gives plenty of aviation-related hits.

Comment: The information published by 2-REG is authoritative. I changed the text to put more emphasize on the link.

Comment: Exactly, it wasn't clear and I wanted more info on the incident. Not sure why the downvotes, please upvote, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Cirrus SR22T owned by Transport Safety Resolutions Ltd according to [this list](https://www.2-reg.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Aircraft-Register-for-Website_20190401.pdf) of the 2-REG Aircraft Registry.

[image]

Comment: Correction - it _was_ a Cirrus SR22T.  Now it's a heap of scrap metal.